# Android Edittext test does not stop at screen boundries

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I added an EditText into a layout for a notepad application. When I tried typing into the EditText I realized that if the text string is longer than the edges of the screen it will just continue past in a straight line instead of going to the next line down. The code for the layout is below.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/noteEditorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteEditor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/enterText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your

`android:layout_width="0dp"`

to

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

instead

or if you insist using the `layout_weight` property, add this line to your `LinearLayout`

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

Comment: I would if I could but StackOverflow is saying that I need a higher reputation to do that.